# Azure nginx from apache .htaccess... php pages are being downloaded and not rendering

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

Moving sites over to Azure App Service - nginx from apache and the .htaccess rewrites are giving me fits.

Below is my default nginx file. I can get the page to redirect but it downloads instead of rendering the php.

But if I add:

`default_type text/html;`

The page will render without the php...

Anything I'm doing wrong here or do i need to edit the nginx.conf (can we even do that with App Service)?

```
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
    #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    #index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    index  index.php;
    server_name  domain.com www.domain.com; 
    port_in_redirect off;

   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    
    # nginx configuration by winginx.com


location /refer {
  rewrite ^/refer /refer.php break;
}

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }
    
    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    
    #default_type text/html;
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    #location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {
       # fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.[Pp][Hh][Pp])(|/.*)$;
       # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       # include fastcgi_params;
       # fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
       # fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
       # fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
       # fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
       # fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
       # fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
       # fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
       # fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
       # fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
       # fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
       # fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
   # }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured this out and hopefully the answer can help people in the future. Put the rewrites in the main location / ... like below.

```
location / {            
        index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # Changed for Laravel
        rewrite  ^/refer$  /refer.php  last;
}
```